# Segmentation Fault issues with a few applications

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, games, segmentation-fault

I've recently upgraded from a VPS to a dedicated server to host my game-servers and IT projects on. However, I face Segmentation Fault issues with two dedicated server applications that run the game-servers.

I've never had these issues before and I'm unaware of how or if I can fix it, since it wasn't an issue in the past. I feel like it's a problem with the software and/or the user permissions *(I don't run the game servers under root, and I don't touch permissions too often, only when needed.)*, though that's just blind speculation.

Is this something I can fix or could it be the software at fault?

The Team Fortress 2 Dedicated Server logs are below. The Segmentation fault also happens to Rust dedicated server.

```
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
BFD: Warning: /home/steam/tf2/core is truncated: expected core file size >= 
193724416, found: 1024000.
Cannot access memory at address 0xf7765908
Cannot access memory at address 0xf7765904
Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.
Cannot access memory at address 0xf7765908
Cannot access memory at address 0xf7765904
debug.cmds:5: Error in sourced command file:
No function contains program counter for selected frame.
email debug.log to linux@valvesoftware.com
Mon Apr 10 16:51:22 EDT 2017: Server restart in 10 seconds
```

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS, and have ensured it is fully up to date.

Comment: `Segmentation fault` means that the program tried to reference an unallocated memory address. This can be caused by bugs in the program,  parameter mistakes excercising bugs, etc.

Comment: I guess it's the software because the segmentation fault occurs when memory, which is out of scope of the program, is attempted to be accessed.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have my answer. I read the definition of Segmentation Fault and for some reason it sounded like permissions. Thank you again for the help.